# No age shown for daughter who "died while the revision was being compiled"

Tags: 19th-century, russia

In the 1850 revision list (ревизские сказки) for my ancestor's household it has no age listed for his daughter; but says only “умерла при составлении сказок” (“died while the revision was being compiled”). Meanwhile his sons all have a phrase like “вновь рожденный в 1847 г.” (newly born in 1847) as well as their age in 1850.

Does this notation mean she died in 1850 or does it refer to the entire time since the previous revision, i.e. she died sometime 1834-1850? All other deaths listed in the revisions note the specific year.

Were there specific circumstances in which the age and birth year were both left out of a revision list, such as a newborn infant dying? (The parents married 1833 and had sons born 1837, 1842, 1844 and 1847, so the daughter could plausibly be the oldest child, the 2nd child or a newborn.)